# Array search on a multidimensional array?

Tags: php

Here is the start of my array:

```
array(19) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "46"
        ["title"]=> string(7) "A"
        ["thumb"]=> string(68) "013de1e6ab2bfb5bf9fa7de648028a4aefea0ade816b935dd423ed1ce15818ba.jpg"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "47"
        ["title"]=> string(7) "B"
        ["thumb"]=> string(68) "9df2be62d615f8a6ae9b7de36671c9907e4dadd3d9c3c5db1e21ac815cf098e6.jpg"
    }
    [2]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "49"
        ["title"]=> string(6) "Look 7"
        ["thumb"]=> string(68) "0bfb2a6dd1142699ac113e4184364bdf5229517d98d0a428b62f6a72c8288dac.jpg"
    }
}
```

How can I use `array_search` on this? I need to get the `id` of an element.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583353/php-recursive-array-searching

Comment: Possible duplicate of a gazillion similar questions here. Also: "what have you tried?". Tsk, tsk, with your reputation score you really should know better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with use of `===` operator compared types have to be exactly same, in this code you have to search string or just use `==` instead `===`.

```
function searchId($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['id'] === $id) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}


$id = searchId('46', $yourarray);
```

Comment: using `==` is preferable here, though... you should assume that not everybody using this function will know it does type-and-value checking