# Return boolean from a recursive function

Tags: php, arrays

I've this array :

```
Array
(
    [self] => Folder A
    [my_data] => Array
        (
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [self] => Folder AA
            [my_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object()
                )
            [20] => Array
                (
                    [self] => Folder AA
                    [my_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object()
                        )
                    [21] => Array
                )
```

I want to check if some data exists inside the array. But condition is, it is a multidimentional array. If I get any single record inside the array (in my_data) then I want to return TRUE else FALSE. For this I've done a recursive function.

```
function checkIfDataExists($tab) {
    $status = true;
    if (!count($tab['my_data'])) {
        $status = false;
    }

    if (count($tab) > 2) {
        foreach ($tab as $subTabKey => $subTabValue) {
            if( $subTabKey != 'self' && $subTabKey != 'my_data' ) {
                return checkIfDataExists($subTabValue);
            }
        }
    }

    return $status;
}
```

But it is always returning FALSE. The above example should return TRUE because there are records inside 'my_data' of [18].

EDIT : Another example that should return TRUE

```
Array
    (
        [self] => Main Folder22
        [my_data] => Array
            (
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [self] => New Sub
                [my_data] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [self] => sub folder 21
                [my_data] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [self] => sub folder 211
                        [my_data] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object()
                            )
```

Comment: Convert it to array and use search function from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583353/php-recursive-array-searching and try

Comment: @VforVendetta It is already an array

Comment: It seems you are excluding `my_data` key in the `foreach`, so second parse isn't happening, therefor it never is `true` again.

Comment: Then use that function I have mentioned in post, may be your code seems to be missing something

Comment: @fpietka I've to exclude the `self` and `my_data` because the inner array is not inside both of them. It is the third key that I've to check again and again

Comment: Where is `$subTab` in your recursive call coming from? I only see `$subTabKey` and `$subTabValue`.

Comment: Also: You should cancel your loop / recursion once you found something, otherwise you just overwrite it with a later value (possibly `false`).

Comment: @pkdq you should have written `$subTabValue` instead of `$subTab`

Comment: @ccKep AAhhh.... how silly. Let me fix and check

Comment: @ccKep I used the solution provided by Pradyut Manna below in comments along with fixing the mistake you pointed. It almost worked apart from one case. I've updated my question with another example that should return TRUE but it returned false

Comment: @ccKep you were right for breaking the loop to overwrite the $status, but its been quite a while scratching my head. Can you please guide me how to break out of the loop when we get a TRUE $status

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkIfDataExists($tab) {
$status = true;
if (!count($tab['my_data'])) {
    $status = false;
}

if (count($tab) > 2) {
    foreach ($tab as $subTabKey => $subTabValue) {
        if( $subTabKey != 'self' && $subTabKey != 'my_data' ) {
            return checkIfDataExists($subTab);
        }
    }
}

return $status;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But this is causing because we can not use return along with variable assignment

Comment: oops sorry then remove  $status varriable

Comment: Your solutions almost worked but in one case it failed. I've updated my question with another example that should return TRUE but it returned false.