# PHP - Proper use of in_array_r in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know that `in_array()` does not work on multidimensional arrays. I tried to implement this in my code:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

But I always get following message

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function in_array_r()

There is a code where I need to check does my value exist in array:

```
class classification {
  foreach ($valueArray as $values => $arrayEV) {
    $valueCode = $arrayEV;
       #NOW I NEED TO CHECK DOES $valueCode EXIST IN ARRAY CALLED '$v'
 ...
```

But when I add

```
echo in_array_r("Irix", $v) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

I get that fatal error.

Comment: Do you get the fatal error for the missing function in the same file that contains the function, or in another file?

Comment: In the same file...Function is defined in classification.php, function is called also in classification.php. Error message => <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function in_array_r() in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml\class\classification.php:82

Comment: If it is defined inside of the class use `$this->in_array_r()` instead of just `in_array_r()`. If it is not please provide the whole class as code to your question.

Comment: It helped me, thank you. Now problem is that it returns me 'not found' in every case, I hope that I will find solution. Thank you one more time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583353/php-recursive-array-searching