# Multi-dimensional array search yields only last level keys

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, search, multidimensional-array

I have a search function which searches for a key value pair in a multi-dimensional array.

I'm trying to search a record recursively for a key value match and if a match is found I need the whole record to be returned. But my function returns only the array in which the key value was found in

**Input:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5a9537b1072e100a423c2777",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "samar",
        "nick_name": "asaa",
        "address": {
            "add2": {
                "city": "BGsLR",
                "state": "Karnataka",
                "PinCode": "580d025"
            }
        },
        "updated_at": "2018-02-27 10:52:47",
        "created_at": "2018-02-27 10:49:21"
    }
.
.
.
```

**My function:**

```
public function search($key, $value)
{

    $results = array();

    $this->search_r(Contact::all()->toArray(), $key, $value, $results);
    return $results;
}

private function search_r($array, $key, $value, &$results)
{
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return;
    }

    if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {

        $results[] = $array;
    }

    foreach ($array as $subarray) {
        $this->search_r($subarray, $key, $value, $results);
    }
}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
   {
    "city": "BGsLR",
    "state": "Karnataka",
    "PinCode": "580d025"
   }
```

So as you can see my function returns only the inner most array of the result where as I need to get the whole entry (from the top level).

What's going wrong here?

***Edit:***

**Expected output:**

```
{
    "_id": "5a9537b1072e100a423c2777",
    "id": "1",
    "name": "samar",
    "nick_name": "asaa",
    "address": {
        "add2": {
            "city": "BGsLR",
            "state": "Karnataka",
            "PinCode": "580d025"
        }
    },
    "updated_at": "2018-02-27 10:52:47",
    "created_at": "2018-02-27 10:49:21"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the top level*?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: i'm not sure if its exactly you want but you can try to change  `$results[] = $array;` by  `$results[] = array($key => $value);`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat the results are part of "address" key in this case, likewise "address" is part of another entry. So I want the top most entry to which the results belong to

Comment: @splash58 please see my comment above

Comment: @SapneshNaik so, do you want to get path from root to desired pair ?

Comment: @splash58 see my edit

Comment: @splash58 I'm not able to put it in proper technical terms but, I'm trying to search a record recursively for a key value match and if a match is found I need the whole record to be returned. But my function returns only the array in which the key value was found in

Comment: get code there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583353/php-recursive-array-searching add check for key and change upper function to `public function search($key, $value)
{
  foreach($this->search_r(Contact::all()->toArray() as $x) {
      if (in_array_recursive($x, $key, $value) return $x;
  }  
  return [];
}`

Comment: *"function returns only the inner most array of the result"* -- it "returns" what you put in `$result` and you put there an array that has the key `$key` associated with the value `$value`. The outer array has different keys and values and it is not available in the function (if it contains the searched key and value it was already added to `$results` by the caller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about efficiency, but you can use combination of [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php):

```
$predicateKey = 'city';
$predicateValue = 'BGsLR';
$result = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($predicateKey, $predicateValue) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($item)
    );

    foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === $predicateKey && $value === $predicateValue) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
});
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b8accf9914126e50b4ebba980386579e6b442a15).